# Why doesn't rotating my matrix upon multiple axis have a determinant of 1?

Tags: c++, math, matrix, graphics, rotation

When I rotate a my Matrix 3x3 on a single axis, it keeps the determinant as 1 as expected. But when I rotate on multiple axis i get a different determinant, is this supposed to happen? If not what am I doing wrong? If so, why not?

TEST:

```
std::cout << (Matrix3::FromEuler(Vector3(0, 0, 45)).GetDeterminant()) << std::endl;
std::cout << (Matrix3::FromEuler(Vector3(0, 45, 45)).GetDeterminant()) << std::endl;
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
1.17678
```

GET DETERMINANT FUNCTION:

```
float Matrix3::GetDeterminant() const
{
    return (e[0] * e[4] * e[8]) + (e[3] * e[6] * e[2]) + (e[6] * e[1] * e[5]) - 
           (e[0] * e[7] * e[5]) - (e[3] * e[1] * e[8]) - (e[6] * e[4] * e[2]);
}
```

FROM EULER FUNCTION METHOD 1:

```
Matrix3 rotX = Matrix3();
Matrix3 rotY = Matrix3();
Matrix3 rotZ = Matrix3();

rotX.m11 = cos(Radians(euler.x));
rotX.m12 = -sin(Radians(euler.x));
rotX.m21 = sin(Radians(euler.x));
rotX.m22 = cos(Radians(euler.x));

rotY.m00 = cos(Radians(euler.y));
rotY.m20 = -sin(Radians(euler.y));
rotY.m22 = cos(Radians(euler.y));
rotY.m02 = sin(Radians(euler.y));

rotZ.m00 = cos(Radians(euler.z));
rotZ.m10 = sin(Radians(euler.z));
rotZ.m11 = cos(Radians(euler.z));
rotZ.m01 = -sin(Radians(euler.z));

//I think this means X->Y->Z because matrix multiplication is backwards. (may be wrong)
return rotX * rotY * rotZ;
```

FROM EULER FUNCTION METHOD 2:

```
Matrix3 mat;

float sx = sin(Radians(euler.x)); //sb
float sy = sin(Radians(euler.y)); //sh
float sz = sin(Radians(euler.z)); //sa
float cx = cos(Radians(euler.x)); //cb
float cy = cos(Radians(euler.y)); //ch
float cz = cos(Radians(euler.z)); //ca

mat.m00 = cy * cz;
mat.m01 = -cy * sz * cx + sy * sx;
mat.m02 = cy * sz * sx + sy * cx;

mat.m10 = sz;
mat.m11 = cz * cx;
mat.m12 = -cz * sx;

mat.m20 = -sy * cz;
mat.m21 = sy * sz * cx + cy * sx;
mat.m22 = -sy * sz * sx + cy * cx;

return mat;
```

(update)

MATRIX VALUES:

```
0.707107, -0.707107, 0,
0.707107, 0.707107,  -0,
-0, 0, 1

0.5, -0.5, 0.707107,
0.707107, 0.707107, -0,
-0.5, 0.5, 0.707107
```

As you could expect, both From Euler methods give the same result so i'm starting to think its not the problem. I'm sorry for pasting so much code, there is a lot of stuff that works together to create this problem...

You should also note that i use a union for the matrix so i can reference elements with (e[], elements[], mXX), I use a column major matrix and the m's first number is the rows, second is the columns ranging from 0-3.

The sources I used for the formula's are 'Foundations of Game Engine Development' book and [this](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions)

(Solution)

I had a bad GetDeterminant function, this is my new one:

```
float Matrix3::GetDeterminant() const
{
    return m00 * (m11 * m22 - m12 * m21) + 
           m01 * (m12 * m20 - m10 * m22) + 
           m02 * (m10 * m21 - m11 * m20);
}
```

Comment: Can you paste in the actual rotation matrix?

Comment: Just updated @AnonSubmitter85

Comment: Since `det(A*B) = det(A) * det(B)` and the determinants of your rotation matrices are 1, the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: I defined `q0` to be a random 3x3 matrix and then scaled each element by `1 / det(q0)^(1/3)`, which forces its determinant to be one. Let `q = q0 / det(q0)^(1/3)`. Using the two rotation matrices you provided, call them `A` and `B`, I get `det(A*q)==1` and `det(B*q)==1`.

Comment: Just checked it with an online calculator and yeah, you're right which means my GetDeterminant() function is bad. I'm currently looking into finding a new formula and I'll give you an update on that. Thanks

Comment: `return (e[0] * e[4] * e[8]) + (e[3] * e[6] * e[2]) + ...` should be `return (e[0] * e[4] * e[8]) + (e[3] * e[7] * e[2]) + ...`

Comment: IT WORKS. Just needed a good formula for the determinant. Thank you very much @AnonSubmitter85

Comment: @JordanChapman Glad to help.